# django - What does created mean?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Will someone please explain to me about `created`, and where and how its being used in django.

I have seen it using in something like this:

```
obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(first_name=’John’, last_name=’Lennon’, defaults={’birthday’: date(1940, 10, 9)})
```

And even in signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Article)
def create_approval(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("created", False):
        approval = Approval.objects.create(article_id=kwargs.get('instance').id)
```

I really need to know this. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit:**

Here, from the above codes:

```
    if kwargs.get("created", False):
```

What does `created` mean here? Does it specify the value of `created` as `False`. Or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django's models gives a convenience method called [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), which looks up for an object based on specified criteria (in `kwargs`). If the criteria do not match, a new object is created.

Now, there is no way for us to determine in the view if the object returned was created or pre-existing (especially if you dont have a `created_datetime` or similar field), hence the `created`. It is a boolean variable, which is set to `True` if a new object was created by the ORM, and set to `False` if an existing object was retrieved.

Now, in your scenario:

```
obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(first_name=’John’, last_name=’Lennon’, defaults={’birthday’: date(1940, 10, 9)})
```

This is saying, get me the `Person` object with `first_name = John, last_name = Lennon, birthday = ...`

If this is not found, create a new one for me.

The `defaults` specify the initial value of the field `birthday` while creating the object in this scenario.

This is also equivalent of writing

```
obj = None
try:
    obj = Person.objects.get(first_name=’John’, last_name=’Lennon’)
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Person.objects.create(’birthday’ = date(1940, 10, 9), first_name='John', last_name = 'Lennon')
```

In the signal's receiver, `kwargs` is a dictionary with custom key-value pairs.
When you look at the signals' documentation, lets say `post_save` has the following signature

```
django.db.models.signals.post_save

post_save(sender, instance, created, raw, using, update_fields)
```

This s the same as

```
post_save(sender, **kwargs) #where the rest of the args are a dictionary saved in **kwargs
```

Here, `created` has a similar meaning. It is notifying the signal whether `instance` was newly created, or updated.

So, if `created = True`, new object was created. `created=False`, object was probably updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please also explain to me, what does `if kwargs.get("created", False):` mean, as in the edit?

Comment: So, does it mean, that when an article is created do something, or else the default value is is False?

Comment: yes you are right. More accurate way of putting it is, when object is created, True else False

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can take some rest! :)

Answer (score 0):

`created` is a boolean return variable of get_or_create(). If the object was created (SQL INSERT) with the get_or_create() call it is `True`, if not (the object was fetched with SELECT) it is `False`.

The second: MyModel.objects.create() forces a create (INSERT).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am just a newbie here, could please maybe elaborate a little more. :)

Comment: @Aamu django is the best documented project I know. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Please have a look at my Edit.